# How to install linkerd as part of an umbrella chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, linkerd

I am trying to install linkerd which is contained in an umbrella chart but I keep getting this error. I think it is because helm can't find the values.yaml file for linkerd to update the crtExpiry. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

I have set the $exp variable, so this is not the problem. This command works if I install only linkerd but not when linkerd is a subchart. I have also tried creating a crtExpiry global property and referencing it in the values.yaml for the linkerd chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the name of the subchart as a prefix.

For example:

--set linkerd2.identity.issuer.crtExpiry=$exp